# Diode ratings question

Tags: diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier

Can I use a 1000 V, 3 A diode instead of a 400 V, 3 A diode?
The dead diode is a [uf5404](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88756/uf5400.pdf), it was in a satellite receiver power supply.

The only ones I can find in the market are [fr307](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/ds26003.pdf) and [1n5408](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88516/1n5400.pdf).

Here's a [picture of the power supply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tMJs.jpg) that I need to replace the diode in. I've marked its location on the PCB.
[image]

Comment: For a clear answer, we would need to see the **schematic** of that supply indicating which diode(s) you want to replace. If the diodes are in the mains rectifier then probably the 1000 V diodes would be OK. If the diodes are in a part of the circuit where only **very fast** diodes can work then maybe you cannot just replace them with any other diode. Probably the diodes need to be "fast" as in the UF5404 datasheet it states: "Ultrafast reverse recovery time" so that would rule out the 1N5408 and also the FR307 (their reverse recovery time is much longer).

Comment: It depends what the diode was doing in the circuit. We can't possibly know.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately i can't find schematics for this power supply, but i have posted a picture and marked the diode's location https://i.imgur.com/OgyW3ys.jpg

Comment: Looks switch mode on the secondary side. Try a fast one?

Comment: The 1N5408 seems more suitable with Vr*Cv = T sufficiently low to match

Answer (score 1):

The diode you've marked on the PCB of your PSU is an ultrafast rectifier designed for high-power switching applications such as the secondary of your power supply, which is where the original diode was installed. The 1N5408 is way, way too slow for this application and will just burn up (and most likely destroy the power supply again). The FR307 is relatively fast (500ns trr) but not quite as fast as the original UF5404 (75ns trr). However, 500ns is most likely acceptable for a SMPS operating at 60kHz or less. You can try it - run the power supply for a minute or two with a FR307, then unplug it and check how hot the diode gets. If it's above 100°C under load, you might have to parallel two diodes because the higher switching losses will leave less room for conduction losses. *Make sure that the primary smoothing capacitor is discharged before you touch anything in the PSU!*

Ideally, though, you'd get a diode with 200ns reverse recovery time or less. Depending on the power supply's output voltage, you might be able to use a faster one with a lower voltage rating. It's quite likely that the engineers designing this PSU just used an UF5404 because it's readily available and cheap, not because they really need a 400V diode. If you have an oscilloscope, you could measure the voltage on the secondary winding that this diode is attached to. The diode has to be able to withstand the full peak-to-peak voltage of this signal. *Do not probe the primary side of the PSU.*

Comment: I'm not sure I agree.  Using the slower part increases the  percentage of the switching cycle (100 KHz in your example) during which switching losses occur from (2*75ns)/10us=1.5% to (2*500ns)/10us = 10%.  This is a significant increase in power dissipation.  So unless you a privy to the thermal analysis that was done, I would look for a faster part.

Comment: And for reliable operation, I would need to see more than just 2 minutes of operation without failure.

Comment: @Digital80 you could probably harvest a diode from the power supply of a dud tv, cd player, laptop psu, pc psu etc. Find some e-waste and you might get lucky. UF5404s are pretty common in this type of application.

Comment: The reverse-recovery time is quite variable; however, the reverse-recovery *charge* stays roughly constant. I just ran the numbers for the FR307 - it will have a substantially larger power dissipation than an UF5404 but two in parallel might do the trick. You're right that it won't work too well at 100kHz though, 60kHz is probably the limit. Even then it'll dissipate around a watt in a typical flyback PSU (like the one in question here). It will, at least, not overheat from switching losses alone, which is why I suggested putting two in parallel.